# non jews and wearing a yarmulka

Tags: kippa-yarmulka

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should one ask a non-Jew attending synagogue to wear a yarmulke?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/should-one-ask-a-non-jew-attending-synagogue-to-wear-a-yarmulke)

When a non jew visits the kotel he has to put on a yarmulka is there a halachic basis for this? Also when a non jew teaches at a yeshiva or goes to a wedding they put one on, is this coming from halacha or from a respect point of view?

Comment: sam, this seems to be an exact duplicate of an earlier question. If you think that this one has the merit to stand on it's own, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry about that when I was typing the title in this question didn't come up on the beg of the list,it was answerd ,trying to get use to the site.

Comment: Don't worry about it, duplicates are an important part of the site too. Duplicates allow future users to more easily find a question that may be hard to find. In this case, you didn't find the original question, but the next guy will find this one, which now links to the original.