# Is a Gentile that keeps Yom Tov Chayav Misa like on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, yom-tov

We say a gentile that keeps Shabbos is chayav misa (death penalty).  Is this also true if a gentile keeps yom tov?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19036/5

Comment: I would add...Death penalty or not, is it forbidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping Shabbat is not necessarily Shabbat - the Gemara (Sanherin 58:2) states it can be on any other day as well.

Resting for a non-Jew is our human intuitive definition for rest (as I understand from [this source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42703&hilite=68a46f9e-1e10-4385-be90-5e07aa99c13e&st=%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99+%D7%A9%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA+%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91+%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%94&pgnum=75)), not keeping Halachic Shabbat.

Apparently, there would be no difference if it's a Yom Tov or Shabbat - he did שביתה at any rate.

The Rambam (Melachim 10:11) says `וכן גוי ששבת אפילו ביום מימות החול אם עשה אותו לעצמו כמו שבת, חייב מיתה, ואין צריך לומר אם עשה מועד לעצמו.`. He continues to say they are not allowed to make up new Mitzvot - so the problem is doing it as a Mitzvah.

On a similar note, Radbaz asks what the problem is if it's on a different day and explains the problem is declaring a certain day of the week as a day of rest, not one-time resting.

I would conclude he has the same חייב מיתה (I've seen places emphasize: this doesn't mean Beis Din will kill him).

Some sources explain this as a violation of the special connection between Shabbat and Yisrael. This can be argued pro or con.

Comment: I'm not seeing "the problem is keeping a day out of seven, not one-time resting" in [the _Radvaz_](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=107869&rid=15012), but if he does say that then wouldn't that argue **against** a prohibition on keeping _yom tov_?

Comment: @msh210, The last line of the Radvaz speaks of declaring a certain day as a day of rest. Both he and Rambam speak about something permanent ("New Mitzvah"). Perhaps this could be rephrased.