# When is it acceptable for a non-Jew working towards Orthodox conversion to grow peyot?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, payot-sideburns

I am working towards an Orthodox conversion, and physical reminders continue to help me on my path as reminders - like tzitzit and kippah. I would like to grow out my peyot, but I am concerned I may offend some of the community members. When is it acceptable for a non-Jew working towards Orthodox conversion to grow peyot?

Comment: I personally have very short peyot, which are more to do with personal comfort and I trim them as necessary. They are only long enough for me to tuck behind my ears, much like in pictures of R' Samson Raphael Hirch. I would advise that if you would prefer to grow peyot in the short term to do so in this manner, as it leaves alternatives for the future so that you won't need to worry about changes like those in @Adam 's answer.

Answer (score 9):

It depends. 
If you mean that until now you have been completely shaving them like a crew cut, then letting them grow a bit should be fine, no one would really notice a major change. ([Click here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/735346/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/halachos-of-peyos-harosh/) for a full explanation on Peyos)

If you mean to grow them out long until they curl around your ears or even longer, well i will tell you what my rebbe told me - "It's much easier to shave your beard then to cut off your peyos."

what he meant was that growing peyos to make an obvious statement about how you express your Judaism is a very real responsibility. if G-d forbid you are in a situation that you will need to cut them off it will be emotionally difficult, much more so than shaving a beard.

There are many Frum orthodox people who don't have long peyot and they have a very deep relationship with Hashem just the same. Perhaps wait a bit. get more involved with your studies and work on the inner stuff of being Jewish. Once you are in a comfortable place there, you can then decide about adding the external stuff!

Much Hatzlacha,

not sure where you are on your journey, but i hope it goes well for you!

(I am a young rabbi who has dealt with a few people going through conversions, not an expert, but i know a little of what you are going through)

Comment: "It's much easier to shave your beard then to cut off your peyos." That's interesting since a beard is usually looked upon with greater significance.

Comment: @Sam that's because having a beard is a requirement, whereas having long peyot is a middat chassiduth

Comment: R' Adam, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for sharing your experience and your rebbe's teaching.

Comment: Non-Jews are not commanded to keep any of the 613 mitzvot. Their responsibility is to keep the 7 mitzvot of Noach. The mitzvah of peyot from VaYikra 19:27, as with all the commandments enumerated in that chapter, distinguishes Israel as being 'Kedoshim'. G-d told Moshe that the commandments enumerated there were to be said to the 'entire flock of the children of Yisroel'. It is not intended for someone who may, in the future, elect to become Jewish.

Comment: @YaacovDeane see response below to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working toward an Orthodox conversion, then you are also working with an Orthodox Rav and Beit Din. Your first source for what you should do prior to your conversion should come from them.

That said, prior to your actual conversion, according to halacha, you have the legal status of being a non-Jew. You are not commanded to keep any of the 613 mitzvot (commandments) that a Jew is obligated to keep. And in fact, in regard to most of them, you should not be keeping them properly. Rather, you should be careful to observe the laws that are required of the children of Noach.

The essence of this idea is found in the story about the disagreements between Yosef and his brothers and what ultimately resulted in his being sold into slavery and sent to Egypt. Both Yaacov Avinu and his beloved son, Yosef recognized that they were in a transitional period between being B'nai Noach and being B'nai Yisrael. Yosef, who received more complete instruction from his father about this, understood that during the transitional period, they still retained the halachic status of B'nai Noach.

His older brothers were of the opinion that they had the legal status of being full-fledged B'nai Yisrael. A few of the practical areas of disagreement are mentioned in Torah. They revolve around kashrut and shechita, social interactions both personal and in business including matters of yichud, all matters of taharah, and even family inheritance.

Those disagreements resulted in Yosef's brothers plotting to murder Yosef and ultimately selling him into slavery. But in the end, G-d revealed that just like Yosef's prophetic dream, where the dream elements representing his brothers and his father and mother would come to bow to the dream element representing Yosef, so too Yaacov Avinu and all his brothers were literally brought by Divine Providence to bow before Yosef HaTzadik, the primary representative of the King (Mishneh l'Melech).

Through this bowing, they acknowledged that the halacha followed the view of Yosef regarding this transitional period, that the 'Kingship', the will of the King of the universe was with him.

It is worth noting that we are to remember this every time a communal sin offering is brought, meaning when we recite the sin offering each day in morning prayers. On Yom Kippur, when recounting the ten martyrs, we also bring this episode to mind. It is one of the central ideas of Judaism.

These two links give some of the details of this concept:

http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/leff/archives/vayeish.htm

http://www.machondaniel.org/displayissue.asp?ArticleID=194#.VnQHsxHtly4

A prospective convert to Judaism, prior to completing the conversion, is also in this transitional period and acts according the halacha that was established by Yosef and upheld by the King of the Universe, the Holy One, blessed be He.

For example, Shabbat is something you should make a point of not keeping fully until you have completed your conversion. If you would find it embarrassing, you can make the violation in private.

In regard to most, the wearing of a head covering is a 'good practice' which is found among all people, Jews and non-Jews. Torah says it is beneficial in helping one to remember G-d above and to live an upright life.

When someone who is not yet Jewish observes the 613 mitzvot, meaning they take on an external appearance of looking Jewish, it leaves open the possibility for negative consequences.

For example, a young Jewish woman may see you and not realize your status. She could overlook her true Bashert (the soul mate G-d intends for her) because her attention is on you. And what if you have a change of heart prior to actual conversion? At any point, prior to circumcision, immersion and standing before the Beit Din to accept upon yourself the yoke of the mitzvot, you can have a change of heart and say no thank you. It is not wrong for you. But for the poor Jewish woman, she has perhaps missed the opportunity of her life as a result of well intentioned 'false advertising' from you.

If you feel a true love for the Jewish people, which according to Rabbi Hillel HaZaken is equated with keeping the entire Torah, you should delay observing the 613 commandments when there is a conflict between your obligation as a Ben Noach and the obligation of B'nai Yisrael until after your conversion is completed.

The word, "mitzvah" (commandment), comes from the root 'tzavtah', which means connection. Any mitzvah, something you are actually commanded to observe, is your way of connecting properly to the Creator of us all. Torah tells us that it is far greater to fulfill what you are commanded to observe than to do something which you are not commanded to do on a voluntary basis. Doing those things which you commanded to do is fulfilling the will of the King of the Universe, the Holy One, blessed be He.

As a non-Jew, you are actually commanded to fulfill the seven mitzvot of the children of Noach. When you properly observe these seven commandments, you are considered completely righteous before G-d and also have a share in the world to come.

Even more than this, since you mention that you are at least learning about the commandment of tzitzit, you should be aware that one aspect of tzitzit that a Jew is to required to think of when performing this commandment is to recall all the commandments of G-d. For a Jew, that means they are to remember the 613 mitzvot of the Torah and the 7 Rabbinic mitzvot. But those 7 Rabbinic commandments are intended to parallel and remind us of the 7 commandments of Noach which G-d commanded on all mankind. The fulfillment of 613 mitzvot of the written Torah which are commanded upon the Jewish people together with the 7 commandments of Noach which are incumbent upon all mankind result in a revelation of G-d's kingship in the world. This is alluded to through the union of 613 and 7 which gives a sum of 620 (כתר), 'Crown', the Crown of G-d's kingship.

Even more than this, we have the explicit saying of the Sages of Israel that, "All sevenths are cherished" before G-d. (כל השביעין חביבין) This includes all those non-Jews who fulfill the 7 commandments of Noach.

At the very least, for you, if in fact you do ultimately convert to Judaism according to halacha, it is possible to think, 'how fortunate am I at this transitional time, that G-d has given me the opportunity to properly fulfill this aspect of the 7 mitzvot of Noach before taking on the new relationship of the 613 mitzvot incumbent upon the Jewish people.

Comment: Someone actually undergoing conversion needs to become accustomed to following all 613 commandments, rather than focusing on the 7 Noahide commandments. The practice today is for gerim to be completely observant in every way by the time they convert. (The major exception are to do some symbolic "aveira" each Shabbos and to avoid wearing tefillin until they convert).

Comment: @Kordovero: That means learning about them from the Rav who is instructing him. It doesn't mean actually doing them. In terms of practice, since we are talking about Orthodox conversion, it follows what is given in Shulchan Aruch. Do you care to provide the source in Shulchan Aruch that says non-Jews should keep and fulfill the 613 mitzvoth?

Comment: The gerus procedure described in the S'A is a bit different than how all contemporary Orthodox authorities rule than gerus must be done. The S'A says just teach him a few mitzvos and their punishments and then convert them, assuming they'll learn to be observant afterward. We don't do that anymore, because now it's too easy to go off the derech. So now gerim keep everything, keeping a kosher kitchen, etc., so they can be completely observant the moment they become Jewish. This is basically the universal practice today among all widely-recognized Orthodox batei din.

Comment: I have been involved in 3 conversions so far, in each one they kept all the mitzvot as they learned them, but wouldn't keep the whole shabbat, UNTIL they got close to their conversion when they have been living as a jew for a while. once they hit that stage they are basically a jew and are not allowed to  break shabbat anymore, as technically becoming jewish is about kabbalat hamitzvos more so than the mikvah, the mikvah is just a technicality but even before that point they are not allowed to break shabbat at all.

Comment: You're saying that someone in the process of conversion shouldn't keep any of the _mitzvot_ besides the 7? That goes against everything I have ever seen in the conversion process.

Comment: What I said was that first and foremost the OP should be directing any questions he has about what he should be doing to the qualified Orthodox Rav and Orthodox Beit Din that are supervising his conversion. The remainder of my response is for his information so he understands what is going on. Until they actually become Jewish they are obligated in the 7 Mitzvot of the Bnai Noach. There are significant differences from Jewish practice. Requirements for conversion are in Shulchan Aruch, Yorah Deah, Siman 268:1-4. If they aren't following Shulchan Aruch, it isn't according to halacha.

Comment: @Kordovero, Shulchan Aruch says that minimal education only in times when the Jewish people are persecuted severely. This is because the times speak to the sincerity and commitment of the potential convert. In times like today, for most of the western world, there is no government sanctioned persecution. That is the basis for the longer and more intensive education process. There are far too many details of concern to address or enumerate in a forum like this. But what I have written concerning his status and obligations prior to actual conversion is accurate and correct.

Comment: @Kordovero, what you are saying in regard to "keeping kosher" is absolutely wrong. Prior to actual conversion, his cooking is bishul Akum. He cannot handle wine. There are numerous potential problems interacting with others. What you call universal practice most definitely is not. It wouldn't surprise me if you have seen this somewhere but that only underlines why some Orthodox conversions, for example, from the United States are being questioned in Israel.

Comment: @Adam, so how do you explain the words of the Aruch HaShulchan, Yorah Deah, Hilchot Gerim, Siman 268:3, which says that there is no conversion without Milah and immersion. If one immersed without circumcision, or was circumcised without immersion, it is nothing. Accepting the yoke of the mitzvot is a declaration of intent made before the Orthodox Beit Din. It is not actually keeping the 613 mitzvot before conversion and transgressing your actual obligations. Perhaps those directing such conversion procedures are not Mumchim.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. They are keeping kosher to the extent they can: eating kosher meat, separating milk and dairy, drinking only (mevushal!) kosher wine or grape juice, etc. They are not technically observing it because they are not commanded yet, but they are practicing being completely observant because that is what they will be expected to do once they convert. So as soon as they convert, they'll toivel their dishes, start wearing tefilin, and stop breaking Shabbat in some minimal way as they may have been encouraged to do beforehand, but otherwise continue as before.

Comment: This is also the practice in Israel. It wouldn't be feasible to observe only the 7 commandments and all of the sudden follow all 613 the moment they convert. Conversion processes in the US are perhaps a bit stricter than in Israel, because here we don't have special tendencies toward leniencies as with Israeli Russian immigrants and soldiers who have Jewish ancestry and yet aren't halachically Jewish.

Comment: @Kordovero, I'm not misunderstanding anything. But there are aspects of this that you aren't considering. A prospective convert isn't living in a bubble. They are most likely among Jews. If the prospective Ger thinks they are for example, keeping kosher, which they are not, Jews around them can come to problems, because of how they are perceived. Boiled wine is irrelevant. Even boiled wine, if handled by a non-Jew is prohibited. Jews are not allowed to waste their own money or the money of others. Requiring the non-Jew to  spend the extra money on kosher is also forbidden. The list goes on...

Comment: @YaacovDeane `Even boiled wine, if handled by a non-Jew is prohibited. ` That is incorrect; if a non-Jew handled wine after it was boiled, the wine remains entirely permissible ([*Avoda Zara* 30a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=30&format=text), [*Shulchan Aruch* YD 123:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4993)).

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure "living as a Jew for a while" constitutes *kabbalas hamitzvos bifnei sh'losha*. And, while you correctly note that *kabbalas hamitzvos* is the most fundamental element of conversion, the conversion does not take effect until after the *t'vila* (Rambam, *Hil. Isurei Bi'ah* 13:6 explicitly follows this tannaitic opinion). Practically, however, see this amazing responsum in *Binyan Tziyon* ([§91](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=591&st=&pgnum=74)) that a convert should observe Shabbos fully after *kabbalas hamitzvos* and *milah* even if the *t'vila* hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Fred, Interesting teshuva! It is only talking about the situation when there has been kabbalat ol hamitzvot before a beit din and milah l'shem habrit. And with all that, the wound has not yet healed, so the prospective convert is physically unable to immerse. He states that the halacha says the individual is still a Ben Noach as he, himself poskined. He then speculates about the source of the minhag in Yerushalyim to allow such an individual to keep Shabbat before immersion. I can say that there is a difference with that generation and those that follow after Matan Torah.

Comment: The generation that came out of Egypt were included in a promise Moshe had that at the time of Matan Torah, no individual that wanted to be included in Bnai Yisroel would be excluded. This was because everyone had a connection to Adam HaRishon. After Matan Torah, the process is different.

Comment: @Fred, To clarify concerning mevushal in practice, many of the better quality wines which are called mevushal, are according to more stringent opinions, like the Tzelemer Rav, not mevushal at all. That is because they rely on the more lenient temperature view and extent of boiling in order to preserve the taste. Depending upon the specific situation, the prospective Ger would be creating a problem for those around him. Again, he should be consulting the specific Rav and Beit Din he is working with.

Comment: @YaacovDeane You're right about the details of the case, but R' Ettlinger ruled with the rabbis of Jerusalem that the convert should observe Shabbos fully (though possibly he should do some non-*m'lacha* work, too, to account for the questioner's view). He presented various arguments why the convert, though not yet Jewish, was also no longer a regular *ben Noach*. (I also wasn't fully convinced by the argument regarding keeping Shabbos before *mattan Torah*, for multiple reasons, but I thought some of the other arguments, such as needing the *mi'ut* from "תושב ושכיר", were quite intriguing).

Comment: Related to your answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40510, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17789, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31082, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20410, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13447, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20498, and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19036.

Comment: @Fred, Of the 4 links, the first 2 are of interest. Saying idea of 'bashert', meaning predestined marriage from before conception, applies between Jew and non-Jew is at best difficult. L'chatechila, someone who comes to convert for a person they are attracted to is refused. And for the Jew, such a relationship is considered forbidden. You could speculate about someone who converts properly and then later meets their spouse. But it would only be speculation.

Comment: Reflecting on the Rabbi Ettlinger teshuvah, he said that the halacha was as he poskined. The Beit Din questioned him afterward saying they had never heard of this. That their practice had been to allow Shabbat observance. Ettlinger then refers to their behavior as a 'minhag'. Considering how minhagim are instituted might point you to the reasoning. In that time, Jerusalem was under the caliphate of the Ottoman Turks. Muslims converting would have been forbidden on pain of death. Non-Muslims could be another story but might give insight into the why. It should point to a "sayag l'Torah".

Comment: Related link: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Minhag

Comment: @Fred, one additional thought regarding the Teshuva in Binyan Tzion. He suggests that perhaps, because of the milah that this has removed the prospective Ger out of the status of being a Ben Noach. That because he fulfills the covenant of Milah, he must keep the covenant of Shabbat. But this ignores the descendants of Yishmael, who also keep this covenant and are forbidden like all Bnai Noach to rest on Shabbat.

Comment: The question from the Binyan Tzion was the p'sak of Rav Asher Lemyl. The Binyan Tzion agreed with the p'sak, but searched for a reason for the minhag Yerushalyim. Concerning the Bnai Yisrael coming out of Egypt, they were the actual descendants from Avraham, Yitzchok and Yaacov. In Avraham's home there were 3 categories of circumcised people. Eliezer, non-Jew & unrelated, Yishmael, non-Jew & son of Avram, and Yitzchok, son of Avraham. Only Yitzchok had inheritance from Avraham. Thus, the difference in status of that generation. It doesn't apply to potential converts today.

Comment: @YaacovDeane:  Had you stopped with the first paragraph, I would have voted up. A convert should only follow what his rav tells him, at least until he's fully Jewish. There are disagreements about whether converts are allowed to start putting on tallis and tefillin, for example, prior to their conversions. Mine said not to; another rav required his candidate to do so before conversion. My rav's daughter recently recalled that 35 years ago, when I first came for Shabbos, I looked like "Tevye". My rav guided me to present a bit more moderate tone while under his tutelage.

Comment: @Bruce James, I can appreciate your comment and when first answering I considered it with just that. But after reflection realized how much misinformation and lack of knowledge there is about these concepts. I recently listened to an interview with Rabbi Israel Hollander (I think) on Arutz Sheva. He is one of the Rabbis on the Sanhedrin in Jerusalem. His specialty is the subject of Bnai Noach. And one comment he made is how most Rabbis do not know or understand this subject at all. Who is, who is not, what they should be doing, etc. This relates directly to prospective Gerim.

Comment: Rabbi Yeshayu Hollander. http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/205104

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on adopting all the customs of a particular chassidic group (shtreimel, long beard, peyos, clothes etc.) upon the completion of your gerus? If so, then you might want to grow long peyos before your conversion. Or if you're planning on being Yeshivish and having very short peyos, an inch or two, then it may make sense to grow them to that length. However, even in these cases, you should wait until you are near completing your gerus, and definitely avoid doing so before checking with your supervising rabbi.

If you're not planning on adopting certain chassidic or Yeshivish minhagim as mentioned above, or if you are not sure, then don't grow out your peyos (though of course you should avoid shaving the area). When you are converting, it is important to send a message to your supervising rabbi and beis din that you are a serious, responsible, and mentally well-balanced individual. When (as do some gerim and baalei teshuvah) you mix and match minhagim--for example, having an modern Orthodox way of dressing but wearing a long beard and peyos--it confuses people, because it is unusual to not follow one consistent set of minhagim.

Conversion can be a long and tricky process, so it's best not to do anything very unusual or out of the mainstream while in the conversion process (such as wearing a "yechi" kippah, using a colorful tallis, or adopting a Yeminite nusach). I have heard a rabbi who has experience in counseling many gerim give this exact advice to gerim.

Nowadays, there are certainly some people who grow long peyos despite not following all the minhagim of a particular chassidic group. See some of the photos [here](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/12/2014/rekindling-flame-neo-chassidus-brings-inner-light-torah-modern-orthodoxy/). However, if you want to do something like this is that is out of the mainstream, it is best to do so after your conversion.

This is not conformity for conformity's sake; it is simply a matter of being prudent when trying to navigate a difficult process. After all, your job during the gerus process is to get used to and become committed to following all the basic halacha required of you, so that you can be completely observant once you convert. Though it may be natural, in the course of finding your spiritual path within Yiddishkeit, to pick and choose certain minhagim that attract you for whatever reason, it is best to avoid this, as least publicly, before your conversion is done.

Comment: Gerim, especially male gerim, are not obligated in any of the minhagim with the possible exception of minhag Yisrael which are customs that have been accepted universally by the entire Jewish people, like for example lighting 8 lights for Hannukah.

Comment: The question asked is not whether they are obligated but whether they may follow these customs during the process of conversion, before the conversion is complete.

Comment: I suggest you go back and review the psak of Moshe Rabbeinu that is recorded in the Chumash concerning the Ben Mitzri who converted and married the Bat Yisrael. Minhag is according to tribe. It is an inheritance from father to son. Male gerim are excluded in most cases with only a few exceptions. It's not a loss. It's actually a benefit.

Comment: Like BTs who don't know their father's customs, gerim in practice in end up choosing their minhagim. Each ger or BT, for example, needs to decide which way they will wrap tefillin, whether they will wear them on chol hamoed, whether they will keep chalav yisroel, whether they will wear a black hat and what kind, etc.; ideally these practices should be consistent but they need not be, hence the issue of picking and choosing I allude to in my answer.

Comment: the convert will most likely be guided by a qualified rav and will choose the minhagim of that rav, even before conversion so that he may learn to join the community he is learning in. we dont follow the psak of Moshe Rabbeinu straight from Chumash we use the poskim for that

Comment: You keep saying that certain things "are best." Why do you think those things are best? Do you have any sources or is this just your opinion?

Comment: It's a matter of prudence and strategy. I'm assuming the prospective ger wants to successfully complete the conversion and be accepted in the Orthodox community.

Comment: @Kordovero, a Ger is not like a Ba'al Teshuva. They are very different and considerations about what kind of practice they follow are likewise, very different. A Ba'al Teshuva is born a Jew and even when their father and grandfather were not observant, it is possible to discover, in many cases, where they were from and what the practices were within their community. A Ger is completely outside of that dimension. It is possible to make some kind of argument that the Rav who teaches the Ger is considered 'like a father'. But minhagim peculiar to the Rav's family are not for the Ger to take on.

Comment: @Adam, like with any other p'sak halacha, later courts have no authority to overturn the decision of an earlier Beit Din unless their members are comprised of greater quantity and quality. In the case of the Beit Din of Moshe Rabbeinu and his Sanhedrin, meaning the 70 elders of his generation, there is no greater authority at this time. The only other option is to say that the current circumstances are different from the circumstances that Moshe's court decided. But over this matter of minhagim and how they relate to Gerim, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

My Rav (Hassidic Orthodox Jew) Owner of Chabad Lubavitch where I reside, he told me before conversion you must prepare yourself before you get into the actual conversion, such as; practicing shabbat, eating kosher, buying and reading books and implementing that into your life. So as far as tzitzit and kippot, by the way, this sounds. Yes, I could see some Hassidic Jew getting angry about what he is wearing because he is a non-jew but if he is genuine and he is %100 sure he's going to go through with this. And he is for sure he won't change his mind in 4 years. Then why is it a big deal preparing yourself to go through an amazing transformation, everyone in the world can convert if they have genuine desire too, so why can't non-jews practice the 613 commandments and shabbat, Purim etc... I personally think it should be encouraged to the ones that truly want it, rather than to dissuade and bring someone's spirit down, we should praise and lift them up. Love thy friend as thyself - this is a great rule of Tora and it applies to ALL HUMANS.

Comment: This does not ansew the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel Yes it does. It just demonstrates why the question is primarily opinion based and should be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Michael! Consider learning more about the site, from this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).