# Which types of light bulbs are 'only' an issur d'rabbanan to activate on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul, lighting, electricity

I'd be very interested to know if anyone has definitive advice on which types of light bulbs are considered an *issur d'rabbanan* (Rabbinic prohibition) vs an *issur d'oraita* (Torah prohibition) to turn on on Shabbat. This is a great discussion forum, and this is my first posting.

I've read various articles and asked some sheylot about it, but it seems the answer depends on technological issues, which themselves are not so clear cut.

The categories of light bulbs currently on the market are:

## Incandesecent

I understand that these are an issur d'oraita because of they involve heating a filament till it glows.

## [Compact fluorescent lights (CFLs)](http://www.bulbs.com/Compact_Fluorescent_Screw--in/results.aspx)

Apparently these are less of a problem than incandescent bulbs,  but some compact fluorescent bulbs use a starter that requires a glowing filament.

The situation is complex because there are sub-types of CFL, including the following (see also the above link)

(1) instant-on; and (2) cold-cathode

The above 2 types may use a different filament (or no filament), so maybe they are less of an issue (or perhaps they still use a hot filament.. one really needs to be an expert in the technology to understand!).

In general, it seems that if a bulb does not reach 'yad soledes bo' temperature then it would not be a Torah prohibition? However, the average 60W equivalent compact fluorescent bulb gets too hot to touch, so is that a problem?

## [LED bulbs](http://www.bulbs.com/learning/led.aspx)

These should be less of a problem d'oraita, as they don't work by means of a glowing filament. However, they apparently can get very hot because the electronic circuit board that runs each bulb can generate a lot of heat, at least with the brighter types.  Do they got so hot that they are a Torah prohibition?

Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong. I'd be very interested to hear any definitive views on this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for sharing this _enlightening_ question with us! You should consider [giving yourself](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/2503) a username more meaningful than 2503. I hope to continue to see you around.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're talking about? Lights are not an _isur_ (prohibition) at all. Are you referring to lighting them on _Shabas_? Extinguishing them on _Shabas_? Lighting them on _yom tov_? Extinguishing them on _yom tov_? Using them to cook milk and meat together? Something else? Please [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/27002/edit) this into the first part of your question to clarify it. [continued in next comment]

Comment: [continued] As the question stands now, "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete" and I'm closing this for that reason. I'll be more than glad to reopen it when the question is clear as to what it's asking.

Comment: What makes you think that the problem with light bulbs is only the heat? There are at least two other well known shabbos issues with them besides that. PS. I'm impressed that you know about cold cathode, it's not as well known as it should be.

Comment: @msh210 I think he wants to know which electric lights are considered fire.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I learned that none of them are. To be fire it must consume/destroy the object that it burns, and light bulbs do not - they are heat, but not fire.

Comment: See the Minchas Shlomo(Rav Shlomo Zalaman)

Comment: @msh210 he had tagged it Shabbat!

Comment: Given the edits, I'm reopening.

Comment: I think reb Auerbach made a book proving its not fire, however on shabboth he says its still ossur because its building. I however don't see how it's building. Someone please explain that for us here.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde_1.htm

Comment: Also it would be interesting to consider **how** said bulb is activated, ie. voice or detecting movement, which many say is only *Uvdin Dechol*.

Comment: My Rosh Yeshiva ruled that incandescent lights may be used for Shabbat candles, with a bracha, but fluorescents or Led can not.  I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: So far the focus has been fire, but there are also opinions that the issur is "final hammer blow" or cooking. See [this ask Moses answer](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/208,252/How-is-turning-on-lights-on-Shabbat-considered-work.html) or [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law).

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115203

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article by Rabbi Michael Broyde & Rabbi Howard Jachter that discusses the entire topic:
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde_1.htm

(side note regarding heating a bulb before it becomes yad soledes- just because the glass encasing of the bulb isn't yad soledes doesn't establish that the filament itself is not.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, I would say that even if you would say that since light bulb filaments get hot, it would only be an issur drabonon. This is because you aren't heating the filament with intent to mold the metal into a shape like a blacksmith rather you are heating the metal filament for light, the case now becomes a מלאכה שאין צריכה לגופה.