# What if someone thinks he is a Jew but his ancestor had not orthodox conversion/was gentile?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

So I thought. These days, most Orthodox Jews would not consider people converted in a Conservative or Reform branch of Judaism jewish, right? But how do you know, as an Orthodox Jew, that you are 100 % jewish? I mean what if his or hers ancestor back back in a time converted in other branches of Judaism and he or she just do not know it? And you cannot prove it? Or there was no proper conversion whatsoever?

Is there some opinion dealing with this?

Comment: Reform Judaism is only about 200 years old.

Comment: How is this different from "what if his or hers ancestor back back in a time was a gentile and he or she just do not know it?"

Comment: Well, because there is no proof that his/her ancestor was converted or not or how. You know we had a WWII here so there is not a lot of information left anyway.

Comment: But everybody considers this family jewish and this family is part of the Orthodox community

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how you've addressed my comments. If you can find a difference from the question I mention please [edit] your post to clarify. Seems to me like 99% of Jews can't prove all their ancestors were Jewish.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get it now. It is the same, you cannot be sure that your ancestor just started "living" in jewish community without "proper" conversion...

Comment: There is question if this person is sinnig while keeping Shabbat (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/if-a-gentile-undergoes-a-non-orthodox-conversion-and-proceeds-to-keep-the-sabba?rq=1) ...and his/hers marriage could be interrmariage in fact. Or it does not count? Would be interested in this Gemara.

Comment: In many countries, and for a long time (I don't know how long!), the Orthodox Rabbi/Synagogue will not conduct a marriage unless it has seen the Kesubos of the mothers (or evidence of conversion).

Comment: There is a general presumption that, unless there is reason to suspect otherwise, we trust someone who claims to be Jewish. Only for certain circumstances (Kohen/Levi) would we check status, and we're provided guidelines for that checking. Assuming someone "doesn't know their parents aren't Jewish," a boy who received a circumcision and accepted to conform to Torah law upon reaching Bar Mitzvah, is there a further requirement for conversion (yes, tevilah is typical, but is it me'akev? Rav Moshe talked about swimming in the ocean as a substitute for tevilah in certain cases...)

Comment: Given the way your question is asked, since the person's parents would have had this checked, then the evidence from the parents' kesuvah would show that the previous conversion was valid (or at least the mother of that generation was a valid Jew).

Comment: Which question are you asking? The body of the question seems to ask "how do I know for certain that my ancestors are Jewish," in which case this is indeed a dupe. But the title asks something entirely different - what happens if someone thinks he's Jewish and finds out there was something wrong with his ancestor's conversion?

Answer (score 3):

There is a concept in the Talmud called "כל המשפחות בחזקת כשרות הן עומדות" (kidushin 76b opinion of the sages against R Meir). This means that every Jewish family has a kosher Jewish status-quo until there is reason to suspect otherwise, and a person is allowed to marry the family without any further investigations (בדיקות).

This is the accepted Jewish law. See Tur EE siman 2, which discusses in length how we should regard an unknown family and the likes. However, if the family is known to everyone there is no doubt that it has a kosher status-quo (according to some even R Meir agrees in such a case). According to the Tur himself even a Kohen may marry into a known family without investigating based on their חזקת כשרות.

Comment: But does this still apply? Back then they didn't have reform conversions. Maybe nowadays there is no longer a chazaka that everythings ok

Comment: There were other branches which was not regarded as "Orthodox" or 100 % "clear".