# What is appropriate covering for non-Jewish men at a Jewish funeral?

Tags: gentiles, clothing, funeral-burial-levaya, social-convention, head

I am going to the funeral of a close friend's sister; the family is Jewish. In the funeral notice it states: "Gentlemen please wear head covering".

My question is: what is an appropriate covering for non-Jewish gentlemen or men?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14679/759

Comment: Alan, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and may we meet next time for a happier occasion! Thanks for bringing your question here.

Answer (score 8):

There is no religious requirement in Judaism for a non-Jewish man to wear a head covering. However, since a public request was made, some attendees might feel that it is disrespectful or insensitive to appear without a head covering. As a practical concern, and out of sensitivity to the family, I would therefore recommend wearing a head covering. Either a [yarmulke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kippah) or a type of hat that would generally be considered appropriate attire at a funeral should be fine.

Comment: To anticipate the followup question about where to get a yarmulke (aka kippah): if your close friend is male and you're comfortable asking, he's probably got one you can borrow; if not, you can get one at a Jewish bookstore for not very much money.  (There could be a basket of them at the funeral, but if a request was made that might suggest not -- and anyway, do you want to rely on that?)

Answer (score 1):

a yarmulke also called a kipa is appropriate or a gentleman's hat of some variety (although I don't recommend one that will stand out too much such as a large top hat)