# Should we ask a non-Jew to wear a kippa for a burial?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, funeral-burial-levaya, kippa-yarmulka

Should we ask a non-Jew to wear a kippa for a burial? He likely doesn't have an obligation to do so. We often ask them in a synagogue (and this [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/should-one-ask-a-non-jew-attending-synagogue-to-wear-a-yarmulke) discusses the reasons) but what about a cemetery?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31960

Comment: i would post an answer that probably would get lots of downvotes. Wearing a kippah is according to many opinions not an obligation, but rather a middath chasiduth. And so under those opinions, if it's not an obligation for a Jew, it certainly isn't an obligation for a gentile. However, if all of the Jews think it's an obligation, or have taken it on themselves as an obligation, then if it would make him feel more like he belongs or feel like he stands out less then one should probably hand him a kippah

Comment: @Fred thanks but I was really asking about the halachic rationale if any, not so much the practicalities of it - but good reference and thanks again!

Comment: @Aaron you are 100% right and I know this. But it has become a minhag shel am Israel which gives it more of an obligatory status than the basic halacha would have been. So now that it is a near-obligation does that extend to all places where Jews congregate. Probably not. I'd say we would ask non Jews so THEY don't feel bad but it shouldn't disturb us if they don't wear a head covering. Interested to see if poskim adressed the issue

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Is this a halachic issue or a social-norm question? If the latter, then location would play a big part.

Comment: @Danny I'm asking about any halachic sources that would bear on that issue

Comment: From my experience, most Gentiles voluntarily wear a kippah at both a Jewish funeral and burial (or they wear a hat / cap). They know that this is common respect to conform with the Jewish custom. Those who are uncertain, ask. Thus, in most cases I have seen, Jews don't even need to ask them.