# Noachide Kippot

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws, kippa-yarmulka

As noachides we are not permitted to wear anything that would cause someone to mistake us as a Jew like tallis, tzitzis, or kippot. As a Noachide when we attend the local 'Temple' which is unaffiliated with any sect, I should not wear a kippah as it may cause someone to mistake me for being Jewish. I just wear normal clothing (modest) as does my wife but how should I cover my head in shuls?

One source says in Noachides should wear a headcovering that s different such as a turban maybe or an Islamic style kufi. I am no good at turbans and I really would not like to wear a kufi if at all possible and be mistaken for a Muslim. What is something practical I can wear? Am I allowed a modest style hat in shuls? Or does it need to be a particular style of hat to be 'halachic' for noachides?

Comment: "As noachides we are not permitted to wear anything that would cause someone to mistake us as a Jew like tallis, tzitzis, or kippot." Where did you learn this?

Comment: From various threads on asknoah. I may have done it injustice by watering it down so much but essentially the ruling is not to wear anything that would cause others to think we are Jewish. Note Rabbi Schochet's comment in [this thread](http://www.asknoah.org/forum/showthread.php?tid=15) and

Comment: If you're in a synagogue, then somebody is going to mistake you for being jewish. Unless you're dressed like a plumber! Even if you wore no head covering, somebody might think you are jewish and not wearing a head covering. It's unavoidable in a synagogue. You could ask the rabbi of a local orthodox shul regarding the halacha. Bear in mind that in an unaffiliated 'temple' there may be many mixed marriages and non jewish people there.   It doesn't sound reasonable or fair to make yourself stick out like a sore thumb (e.g. turban).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Noahide phenomenon -- the practice of identifying onesself as a Noahide as a religion in itself rather than converting -- is fairly recent,  there is not yet a large body of halachic literature on what Noahides should do.

However, there are some Orthodox rabbis who have written books about Noahides (some are only available in Hebrew), some rabbis who have published a siddur for Noahides, called Service of the Heart, and other rabbis who have advised or otherwise helped or supported Noahides or their organizations. I recommend contacting these rabbis and asking them what you should do about head coverings.

This is not related to your question, but given your comment about the Temple, I should mention that they would probably tell you not to attend a non-Orthodox synagogue.

It is normal and accepted for non-Jews visiting synagogues to wear a kippa while in the building (see this thread: [Should one ask a non-Jew attending synagogue to wear a yarmulke?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/should-one-ask-a-non-jew-attending-synagogue-to-wear-a-yarmulke)). However, if you would like to avoid doing that, my own guess would be that wearing any hat (other than a hat specifically associated with Jews) would be the best option.

Comment: I remember learning somewhere (I think it was in Mishne Torah) that 'bene Noach' should of course follow their laws, but are not allowed to make their own religion (even if it would not strictly speaking transgress any of the 7 mi'swoth). 
In this light, I would avoid speaking about Noachide as a "religion". Rather, it's a way of live that is in accordance with Hashem's will for humankind.

Answer (score 2):

it's regular that someone not jewish wears a kipa while visiting a shul. I don't think there is an need to be concerned about wearing a kipa. More importantly would be if someone offers you an aliya or to lead the tzibur to politely decline. I imagine the gabbai will be grateful for your honesty.

Answer (score 0):

There are styles of dress which are quite iconically jewish that to most observers may cause a person to mistake someone as jewish.

Each part of dress in the upcoming list on it’s own may not cause someone to mistake you for being jewish but certainly an ensemble which includes a few of these features together should be avoided for a Noachide.

Any list of jewish dress cannot be comprehensive, the following list is a broad generalization of the features of dress which are most unique; that to an observer might cause confusion as to the persons religious observance. 
This list is mostly in regard to men, if it is requested I could add women’s dress.

> Black hats. 
>   Shtreimel hats.
>   Kippah or Yamulke.
>   Wearing a Tallit (prayer shawl).
>   Tzitzis (fringed garments).
>   White dress shirt with black pants. White dress shirt with a black jacket. Long black coat.
>   Black shoes with visible white socks. Rimless glasses especially with a titanium frame. Black framed
>   glasses, especially oval or circular. 
>   Circular glasses and a full beard longer than 2 centimetres.
>   Wearing a short scarf over a jacket.
>   Wearing a scarf in any season
>   other than winter. Wearing a scarf indoors. Any display of jewish
>   symbolism like the Star of David or Menorah or a pattern with such
>   imagery.
>   Blue tie with a white shirt and black pants.
>   Carrying or wearing a Tefillin or Phylactories (leather black box and strap).
>
> Payot, the long hair just on the sides of the head. Long full beard esp
>   with uncut corners. Long beard with short hair. Long beard with long
>   hair. Long beard with a black hat.

A simple way to dress in such a way that would avoid confusion would be casual western wear, western in the cowboy sense. Plaid patterned shirts, blue jeans and brown boots. You could wear any shirt with snap front pockets or embroidery on the chest without a jacket or with a bomber jacket.

You can wear coloured slacks pleated or not with brown shoes or boots.

For a hat you have many options. You could wear a brown wide-brim hat, a baseball cap, a woven or staw hat, a coloured ascot cap, beanie, or even a french beret.